# multiplying and dividing `unit` objects in `R` `grid`

Tags: r, plot, grid

When positioning plots with the `grid` library in `R` you often need to divide or multiply lengths:

```
> library(grid)
> x <- unit(3, "cm") + unit(2, "pt")
> z <- x / 2
Error in Ops.unit(x, 2) : operator '/' not meaningful for units
```

How to to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to do this, it does not contain any error checking and the intermediate step may depend on the currently open device (in fact if there is no open device, this will open one):

```r
library(grid)

`/.unit` <- function (x, y) {
  x <- convertUnit(x, "pt")
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  unit(x / y, "pt")
}

x <- unit(3, "cm") + unit(2, "pt")

x / 2
```

returns:

```r
[1] 43.6791338582677pt
```

Comment: could also multiply by 0.5

Comment: all the fun with with implementing the `/` function and I forgot to check if `*` was implemented :-), put it as an answer and I'll accept it. I think I tried something like `unit(3, "cm") * 1 / 3` which doesn't work, because of left to right precedence.